# How to target dynamic generated id {{element}} inside angular Directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, directive

I have a requirement where I have created a directive like below:

```
app.directive('popOver', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // get template
            var templateId = element.data('popover-template');
            var templateHtml = $('#' + templateId).html();
            // compile content and class
            var popover_content = $compile(templateHtml)(scope);
            var popover_class = element.data('popover-class');
```

and in the html page i have passed the ID as angular expression like below

```
data-popover-template="{{field.popoverid}}"
```

After running the code i am getting the error like `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {{field.popoverid}}`.

Could someone help me with the issue?

Comment: Try this `data-popover-template="field.popoverid"`

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response, After passing this this issue got resolve now i how to pass the same in a ng-tempate like below <script id="{{field.popoverid}}" type="text/ng-template"> <div class="popover-header"> <div class="col-md-7">{{field.value}}</div> </div> </script>

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory: `data-popover-template` expects an expression. So try this:

```
data-popover-template="field.popoverid"
```

Expression interpolation result `{{}}` is not an expression anymore, so directive can't set up data binding in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response, After passing this this issue got resolve now i how to pass the same in a ng-tempate like below <script id="{{field.popoverid}}" type="text/ng-template">
            <div class="popover-header">
             <div class="col-md-7">{{field.value}}</div>
            </div>
           </script>

Comment: This line is showing undefined error : var templateHtml = $('#' + templateId).html();

Comment: I don't think you can have dynamic template id. Looks like you are using popover AngularUI directive wrong. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create dynamic popover based on the JSON data response, both the button and the popover so i would like to assign the popover id and the target id both form JSON data.

Comment: Try with simple `<div id="...">` instead of script?

Comment: I am returning the value form json file using field.popoverid:"popoverId" and passing the same inside the script tag. After removing the {{}} i am not getting the value form json file. Is there any other way to fix this issue

Comment: Can you create a demo?

Comment: I have uploaded the files in the below location could you please download and check provide the solution https://www.dropbox.com/s/n0zcl712bxqin9z/DynaimiForm.zip?dl=0

Comment: Did you get my requirement?

Comment: Please find the below plnkr link and suggest me how to proceed further http://plnkr.co/edit/nwgFxsHgZjVzqLuMdB9Z?p=preview

Comment: Hi, Did you get any chance to look into this issue..Thanks